# IIS web application becomes bizarrely unresponsive after certain requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, iis

**Windows Data Center 2016, IIS 10, ASP.NET 4.5 MVC 4.0.**

This issue (or something similar to it) used to happen very rarely, with an employee's computer in the office, where the server would become unresponsive for them.  They could open a private browsing window and use the site, or *rebooting the server would allow them to use their normal browser again*.

The server is hosted on AWS.  There are some admin tasks that have been more convenient to actually execute from a browser on the server itself.  Recently, we've experienced a more consistent and intense version of the issue when using the browser on the server itself.

The site will respond normally, until we hit a particular URL.  Once we hit that URL, then (almost**) ALL URLs on the site that we hit will appear to hang for a minute or more, then the client will report `The connection was reset`.

Recycling the application pool or restarting the site or even IIS will not resolve this issue.  Requests from ANY browser on the server will hang and fail in this way, *until the server is rebooted*!

We've enabled Failed Request Tracing for ALL HTTP status codes, and these requests have logs written for them.  They look completely normal, from what i can tell, until the very end, when we see this:

```
819.
GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_START

22:27:08.101

820.
GENERAL_RESPONSE_HEADERS
Headers="Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Encoding: deflate X-Powered-By: ASP.NET "
22:27:08.101

821.
GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER
Buffer="%ED}{s%DB%B6%D2%F7%DF%F6L%BF%03%A23S%DB%E7%89$_%928Mbw%1C%DB%89%9D%F8%92Zv%DC%F6%BCg4%14%09I%B4)%92%E1E%B6%D2%C9w%7Fq%A %A4%08%1A%ECI%EB>%F3%9CF&w%97%D8%1F%16%0B`%B1"
22:27:08.101

822.
GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_END
BytesSent="0", ErrorCode="The semaphore timeout period has expired. (0x80070079)"
22:27:27.007

823.
GENERAL_REQUEST_END
BytesSent="0", BytesReceived="1029", HttpStatus="200", HttpSubStatus="0"
22:27:27.007
```

NOTE that ~20 seconds pass before the GENERAL_RESPONSE_FLUSH_RESPONSE_END, and that it reports 0 bytes sent and "The semaphore timeout period has expired. (0x80070079)".  This is also reflected in the IIS web log for the request, that includes values like the following:

```
sc-status 200
sc-substatus 0
sc-win32-status 121
sc-bytes 0
cs-bytes 1029
time-taken 19584
```

I've read that the `sc-win32-status 121` corresponds to "The semaphore timeout period has expired.".

This seems extremely bizarre, especially in how it seems to depend on a relationship between the server and a particular client.  NOTE that, when this issue is happening on the server, remote clients can still interact with the site just fine.

Any insights or direction on where to dig next would be MOST appreciated.

** There is one URL on the site that works just fine, even when the issue is happening.  No idea why, or what makes it special.  It's a dynamically generated robots.txt, here's its response headers:

```
Cache-Control private  
Content-Encoding deflate  
Content-Length 31 
Content-Type text/plain; charset=utf-8  
Date Fri, 17 Sep 2021 22:56:14 GMT 
X-Powered-By ASP.NET
```

Comment: It took 20 seconds to generate the response of this page so definitely you should analyse further. But without a profiler, it is often difficult to know what exactly happens under the hood. So you should first try to learn how to use a performance profiler.

Comment: First, you can open EventView and try to see if you can find any useful information. The second step, if possible, deploy the program on other servers for testing. If it runs normally, you can be sure that there is no problem with the program, which is the cause of the server itself.